# how to run existing Django project

Tags: python, django

I'm new with python(don't know anything about it), and also in Django... so question is, what and how, step by step, I need to launch existing Django project which I got from github...
so, what I have done already:

- installed python
- created virtual environment
- run `python mange.py migrate`, but it showed many errors(and I don't know what to do with it and how to fix them), because I can't even connect to DB(previously I worked with MySQL where I can connect by myself and do selects to check something in DB), but now this project uses SQLite3, and I don't know how I can check this database
- run `python manage.py runserver` and I can see my webapp at localhost...

So, main question is, how to properly launch existing Django project?

Comment: Please finish this really helpful https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/

Comment: That's the proper way to launch a Django project in development mode. Is there an issue here?

Comment: So... you "don't know anything about Python"... And you want to work on a pre-existing Django Project? You get "many errors" that you have no idea how to handle... Do you expect people here to teach you? How about you learn Python first, then learn Django by at least building a small example project for yourself, then try working on an existing project, and only then, once you run into some concrete problem, go to Stackoverflow and post a proper question?